# Not getting any response from the server in case of some requests with asyncio and aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, python-asyncio

I am trying to send asynchronous requests in python using asyncio and aiohttp. While I am trying to make multiple requests all at once and sending them all at once to the server I am getting back response status as 200 for most of the requests. The problem I am facing is with a handful of requests pending at the end which are always in the range of 5 to 50 no matter whether I make 200 requests or  1000 requests.(Note that I don't face any problem in case of making just 100 requests and the program completes successfully. Its only when I go above 100 requests.) For these 5 to 50 requests pending at the end I don't get any response code or anything whatsoever and hence my program stays stuck and doesn't get completed.
I know that making a lot of requests via a script can result in a temporary ban from the server. But in that case I should be getting a 403 status code at least right...? But I am not getting anything for those 5 to 50 requests pending at the end and for all the other request which got completed other than those pending requests I am getting a 200 status code.
Here is my code..

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time

async def make_request(session,link,i):
    async with session.get(link) as response:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        print(len(asyncio.tasks.all_tasks(loop)))  #To see how many requests/tasks are pending in the event loop
        print(f"request:{i}")
        print(response.status)
        # print(response.status)

async def make_task(link):
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(make_request(session,link,i)) for i in range(no_of_requests)]
        await asyncio.wait(tasks,return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED)  #Getting same outcame with .gather as well.


asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
asyncio.run(make_task("https://ocw.mit.edu"),debug=True)
```

[Here is a ss with number of requests = 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwOTm.png)
[Here the number of requests are 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWi2d.png)
[Here the number of requests are 1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiT0n.png)

Please can anyone suggest what is actually happening here? I am not able to understand if the server is blocking me and if so why am I not getting some 40X status code in response?

Answer (score 1):

> But in that case I should be getting a 403 status code at least right...?

Not necessarily. The server could chose to not send a response at all if it thinks it is under a DoS attack.

I would suggest testing against a server of your own to rule that out.

As far as your client not finishing due to unanswered requests you should keep track of them and somehow cancel them before termination. You can have asyncio return a future for a request that you can later on use to cancel it.